# Не работает states в saltstack c использованием модуля dockercompose.pull

Tags: python, docker-compose, saltstack

При запуске `states(sls)` `salt` выдает ошибку.

Сам `/srv/salt/docker/init.sls`:

```
flask_app:
  dockercompose.pull:
    - path: /srv/docker/flask
    - service_names: flask
```

```
$ salt -G 'roles:flask' state.apply docker

scw-1:
----------
          ID: flask_app
    Function: dockercompose.pull
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'dockercompose.pull' was not found in SLS 'docker'
              Reason: 'dockercompose.pull' is not available.
     Changes:

Summary for scw-1
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:   0.000 ms
```

Делаю все по документации: [dockercompose.pull](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dockercompose.html#salt.modules.dockercompose.pull)

Comment: это сообщение от миньона. возможно, он более старой версии, чем указано по приведённой вами ссылке: *New in version 2016.3.0.* // см. вывод `$ salt-run manage.versions`

Comment: Master:
    2016.11.6
Up to date:
    ----------
    scw-1:
        2016.11.6

На мастере и миньонах версии идентичны, т.к. ставились с офф репы.

Comment: вроде бы, должно работать. единственное, что меня лично смущает (потому что с этим никогда не работал) — использование `init.sls`. попробуйте перенести содержимое `/srv/salt/docker/init.sls` в `/srv/salt/docker.sls` и повторить ту же команду (каталог `/srv/salt/docker` лучше перед этим переименовать или удалить).

Comment: Сделал как Вы посоветовали, но увы, результат прежний.
Заметил, что если на salt-master выполнить команду
salt -G 'roles:flask' dockercompose.get /srv/docker/flask
То команда выполняется корректно.

Comment: кажется, понял. dockercompose — это [execution-модуль](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/), а аналогичного [state-модуля](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/) я не наблюдаю. следовательно, в sls-файле это работать не будет, только в виде непосредственной команды (как вы и написали).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dockercompose](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dockercompose.html) — это «[execution-module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/)» (выполняемый модуль), который «работает» только в виде команды:

```
$ salt миньон(ы) модуль.функция [аргументы]
```

а в списке «[state-modules](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/)» (модули состояния) его нет, потому в файлах описания состояния (синонимы: state-файлы, sls-файлы) функции этого модуля и недоступны.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня была мысль на счет этого, но не был уверен и не знал о такой возможности.

Comment: теоретически (если очень нужно запихнуть вызов функции `dockercompose.pull` внутрь state-файла), можно воспользоваться функцией `cmd.run` и запускать команду (она будет выполняться на миньоне) `salt-call параметры`. но тогда надо самостоятельно хранить состояние (выполнена/не выполнена), например, с помощью grains. // я не стал писать всего этого в ответе, так как эта тема довольно объёмна.